# GWT IFrame Javascript error

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, gwt

I have a gwt module I'm trying to load into my host page. It's a pretty standard routine:

```
public class TimeFvHelper implements EntryPoint {

/**
 * This is the entry point method.
 */
public void onModuleLoad() {        
    ChargeToTreePresenter presenter = new ChargeToTreePresenterImpl(new ChargeToTree());        
    RootPanel.get("divPicker").add((Widget)presenter.getView());        

}
```

Usually it works fine with out problem.  However when i open the webpage using IE9, first time I have no problem.  However if I reload the page or back out then come back in i get the following error:

`Unable to get value of the property 'location': object is null or undefined`

This is in the nocache.js file generated during compilation, specifically in the maybeInjectFrame() method:

```
  var frameInjected;
  function maybeInjectFrame(){
    if (!frameInjected) {
      frameInjected = true;
      var iframe = $doc.createElement($intern_36);
      iframe.src = $intern_37;
      iframe.id = $intern_1;
      iframe.style.cssText = $intern_38;
      iframe.tabIndex = -1;
      $doc.body.appendChild(iframe);
      $stats && $stats({moduleName:$intern_1, sessionId:$sessionId, subSystem:$intern_2, evtGroup:$intern_8, millis:(new Date).getTime(), type:$intern_39});
      iframe.contentWindow.location.replace(base + initialHtml);    // <-- Here
    }
  }
```

I've seen alot of posts in the last two days saying that IE9 has issues with iframes.  Is that what's going on here?   Any ideas of a workaround?

-Ian

Comment: IE9 support was added in GWT 2.3. If you are using a version less than that you need to add a meta tag to tell IE9 to behave like IE8: `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8" />`

Comment: I am using GWT 2.3, but i tried that anyway, and the error still exists.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `xsiframe` linker instead of the default `std` one.

It still uses an iframe for sandboxing (so that scripts loaded in the page have no impact on GWT's code) but do not change the iframe's location (it instead writes into the iframe); and it has many more features: http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/issues/list?can=1&q=xsiframe+status%3AFixed

Comment: Good idea, but same basic error.  The nocache.js file attempts to create the iframe, get a javascript error saying `Unable to get value of the property 'document': object is null or undefined`.    Looks like when IE creates the iframe element (the 2nd time) the contentWindow property is null.

Answer (score 0):

I see the same problem, and I don't have a solution.

But here is the code including the values of the intern'ed strings.

```
function maybeInjectFrame(){
if (!frameInjected) {
  frameInjected = true;
  var iframe = $doc.createElement('iframe');
  iframe.src = "javascript:''";
  iframe.id = 'application';
  iframe.style.cssText = 'position:absolute;width:0;height:0;border:none';
  iframe.tabIndex = -1;
  $doc.body.appendChild(iframe);
  $stats && $stats({moduleName:'application', sessionId:$sessionId, subSystem:'startup', evtGroup:'moduleStartup', millis:(new Date).getTime(), type:'moduleRequested'});
  iframe.contentWindow.location.replace(base + initialHtml);
}
```

}